# Not opening new page throught JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick, window.location

I have a script that gets throught parameter the new page andthe redirects to this page.
my function:

```
function openPage(page) {
    alert("Pressed the button!"); //working
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/Edas/" + page; //not working
}
```

and my button:

```
<button id="btnViewMonthlyPurchaseReport" onclick="openPage('monthlyPurchaseReport.html')">View Monthly Purchase Report</button>
```

I think my problem is in my base URL ("localhost:8080/Edas/"), but really don't know how to fix it.
Thanks!!

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Hmmm, it´s working for me..... what error did you get?

Comment: Do you have the button inside of a `form`? If yes, then the `action` of the `form` could/is (not sure if it is browser dependent) used. So you need either make the `button` not to submit the `form` or use `return false;` at the end of your function.

Comment: Can it be that your server does not like capitol letters in the url?

Comment: Yeah, my problem was that the button was in the wrong place (inside a form), but thanks!

Comment: @t.niese that was my problem! thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the comment the problem was that the button was inside of a `form` element.

The problem is that a button without a `type` attribute will submit the `form`, which would (not sure if in every browser) result into the described problem, that the `window.location.href = ...` has no effect and that the page would be *redirected* to the url defined in `action`. If `action` is not defined in the `form` then it is the the current url.

You have different options to solve this:

1. You could move the button out of the form (if it would not affect usability)
2. Change the `type` of the button to `button` (`<button type="button">View Monthly Purchase</button>`) - the default behavior without a type is `submit`
3. You could place a `return false;` at the end of your `openPage` function to prevent the default behavior (this is similar to **2.** but with the difference that the `button` would still be marked as a `submit` button which could be important for usability in some situations).

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

***JS***

```
var url = window.location.href;
var dirnames = url.split('/');
function openPage(page) {
   alert("Pressed the button!"); //working
   window.location.href = "http://"+ dirnames[2] +"/Edas/" + page; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're correct in saying that your issue is in the URL.

Where is your monthlyPurchaseReport.html?  If it is in the same directory as where the html with your button is, simple use:

```
function openPage(page) {
   alert("Pressed the button!"); 
   window.location.href = page; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was: my button was wrongly inside a form, which @t.niese clearly explained why.
Thank you all for the help!